# Customize Selection in Calendar Control

Tags: c#, asp.net, calendar

I am using a Calendar Control in Asp.Net. The Condition which i want to implement is that "If user selects a particular weekday from a week, He should not be able to select any other date from any different week". Like, All the selections should be made within one week only. But i am not able to figure out how to disable the rest of the weeks apart from the week in selected date.

Comment: could you provide us with what you have so far

Answer (score 0):

I would go about it like this.. when the selected date is changed, get the start and end of that particular week. Then, when each day is rendered, ensure that day falls within that week range.

```
private DateTime? _firstDayOfWeek;
private DateTime? _lastDayOfWeek;

protected void yourCalendar_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var selectedDate = yourCalendar.SelectedDate;

    DayOfWeek firstDay = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfWeek;

    _firstDayOfWeek = selectedDate.Date;
    while (_firstDayOfWeek.Value.DayOfWeek != firstDay)
        _firstDayOfWeek = _firstDayOfWeek.Value.AddDays(-1);

    _lastDayOfWeek = selectedDate.Date;
    while (_lastDayOfWeek.Value.DayOfWeek != _firstDayOfWeek.Value.AddDays(6).DayOfWeek)
        _lastDayOfWeek = _lastDayOfWeek.Value.AddDays(1);
}

protected void yourCalendar_DayRender(object sender, DayRenderEventArgs e)
{
    if (_firstDayOfWeek.HasValue && _lastDayOfWeek.HasValue)
    {
        // There are dates to work with now, so check to see if the day falls
        // outside of the week range...
        if (e.Day.Date.Ticks < _firstDayOfWeek.Value.Ticks || e.Day.Date.Ticks > _lastDayOfWeek.Value.Ticks)
            e.Day.IsSelectable = false;
    }
}
```